# How to resolve the unit test warning to have unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-key-index

```
function OperatingHoursList(props: OperatingHoursProps): JSX.Element {
  const provOperatingHoursList: JSX.Element[] = [];
  if (props.operatingHours) {
    props.operatingHours.forEach(
      ({ open, close }: { open: string; close: string }) => {
        const openTime = open;
        const closeTime = close;
        if (typeof openTime === "string" && typeof closeTime === "string") {
          provOperatingHoursList.push(
            <div css={popupTimeText}>{`${timeFormatConversion(
              openTime
            )} - ${timeFormatConversion(closeTime)}`}</div>
          );
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    provOperatingHoursList.push(<div css={popupTimeText}>Closed</div>);
  }

  return <div css={popupBottomTextTimeSection}>{provOperatingHoursList}</div>;
}
```

I am having a function where I am pushing the data into one array, I am facing the below error.

[image: Facing the warning to have the key]

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is using index of element as a key

```js
if (props.operatingHours) {
props.operatingHours.forEach(
  ({ open, close }: { open: string; close: string }, index) => {
    const openTime = open;
    const closeTime = close;
    if (typeof openTime === "string" && typeof closeTime === "string") {
      provOperatingHoursList.push(
        <div key={index} css={popupTimeText}>{`${timeFormatConversion(
          openTime
        )} - ${timeFormatConversion(closeTime)}`}</div>
      );
    }
  }
);
} else {
  provOperatingHoursList.push(<div key="closed" css={popupTimeText}>Closed</div>);
}
```

Comment: But here we are not pushing that index to else condition and when return we are combining and all the results right there need to add index, in your case only added index for the if condition but not for the others

Comment: In the else condition, it's only have one element. So you can add an custom key like this: ```key="closed"```. I updated my answer. Can you try again ?

Comment: in else if we keep closed as static there is possibility to have multiple else in such a case key will be duplicate keys should be always unique